# N-to-N relation with ability to alsp show items not associated with any

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have 3 tables inside my SQL database: users, groups and users_in_groups (N-to-N relation table).

When user is requesting a list of other users, he can get only contacts which are associated with his groups. To handle it I am getting IDs of user's groups and looking for other users in groups with this IDs.

But now I need to add list of users who are not associated with any group.
Solution I am thinking about is to make separate request to know user IDs which are not listed in users_in_groups table by adding NOT IN (user IDs from users_in_groups).

Comment: You probably only need a simple query here.  But, you should add sample data and the expected output, to make this question concrete.

Comment: What is your question? PS This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want users not in any groups, you can use `not exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from user_in_groups ug
                  where ug.user_id = u.user_id
                 );
```